# C++ Linux Shell - Using Pipes, Fork, and Exec over a Command Vector

Tags: c++, linux, shell, vector

I'm writing a shell for Linux in C++. My main concern is being able to pipe commands indefinitely. Example:

```
ls | cat -A | cat -A | cat -A
```

To do this, I've parsed the input string and made several unix_command objects and push_backed them into a vector. The unix_command struct provides the information needed to run the command, like its name and args.

I need to loop over the vector, set up the pipes so that the current process gets input from the previous process, and continue until the end of the vector. I am doing this with a for-loop and a bunch of dup2 commands, but with no luck. As of now I am getting weird infinite-looping behavior.

```
if(cmdVector.size() > 1){

        int filedes[2]; // filedes[0] is for reading, filedes[1] is for writing.
        pipe(filedes);  //Makes a pipe

        //STARTING OVER ON PIPING
        dup2(0,filedes[1]); // Sets write end of pipe to standard input (keyboard)

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < cmdVector.size(); i++){
            //Do the piping, fork, and run() operations in here!!
            pid_t pid = fork();
            if(pid == 0){   //Child
                if(i != cmdVector.size() - 1){  //As long as this isn't the last command
                    dup2(filedes[WRITE],1); //Set writes of the process here
                    close(filedes[READ]);
                    close(filedes[WRITE]);
                }
                cmdVector[i].run(); //Runs command and calls exec


            }
            else{
                wait(NULL);
                dup2(filedes[READ],0);  //Set input of the main process here, because it forks into the next process, right?
                close(filedes[READ]);   //So if this loops back around and forks, will the child still have the pipe as its input?
                close(filedes[WRITE]);
            }
        }
        dup2(0,0);  //Resets read and write back to normal, hopefully
        dup2(1,1);
    }
    else{   //Just one process, no piping
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){   //Child
            cmdVector[0].run();
        }
        else{
            wait(NULL);
        }

    }
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Full shell.cpp file if you'd like to run it: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwN_NTSpWmSzWmMzVEl0UzNDZEk

MakeFile: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwN_NTSpWmSzTVNSdWxSQWJzYzA

Comment: On each iteration of the loop, the parent process strangely `wait()`s for the child process to exit. Which goes against the intent of starting all of these pipelined processes together. This may not be the only issue, and no authoritative answer is possible without a [mcve]; but this is one obvious bug.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think that is it. The parent represents the main process of the shell, it must wait for the child to finish before moving on, because it is possible for the prompt be reprinted before a process has returned.

I could provide y'all with my entire file of code, but much of it is outside the scope of the problem. I'll post a link to the file if I can.

Comment: If your intent is to set up a pipeline of commands, waiting for the first child to terminate will be a waste of time, since the first child will block writing to its standard output, and the parent process will not start the next child process, that reads from the pipe, until the first child terminates. A real shell starts all child processes in a pipeline, simultaneously. Unfortunately, stackoverflow.com is not a free debugging service, and it's unlikely that anyone will debug your own code for you.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean about waiting now. Could you explain how this child pipeline is implemented? Is it similar to my idea, or different altogether?

Comment: See https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Programming-UNIX-Environment-3rd/dp/0321637739/ref=pd_sbs_14_t_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=S818NDAVCQTQ30HQFAG1